# Numerical solution needed for the quadratic equation (spheres)

Tags: spherical-coordinates, least-squares

There are three point coordinates $A(x_1,y_1,z_1),B(x_2,y_2,z_2),C(x_3,y_3,z_3)$, where $z_1=z_2=z_3$
Now,

$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2=d_1^2$ this equation can be written for my system as

$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+h^2=c_1 \cdot h^2$(where $c_1$ is a constant and $h$ is a unknown variable mainly vertical distance)  so for three point i get three equation like

$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+h^2=(c_1 \cdot h)^2$

$(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+h^2=(c_2 \cdot h)^2$

$(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2+h^2=(c_3 \cdot h)^2$

now i have three equation and three unknown variables $(x,y,h)$ to find out the three unknown by using numerical method i used least square estimation method ( i don't know any other numerical method for these kind of equations) , for using least square estimation i used $2 \cdot M^T \cdot M \cdot X=M^T \cdot D$ so i need another equation for point D$(x_4,y_4,z_4)$ also $z_4=z_1=z_2=z_3$ and equation
$(x-x_4)^2+(y-y_4)^2+h^2=(c_4 \cdot h)^2$

in least square equation where

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}(x_4-x_1)&(y_4-y_1)&(z_4-z_1)\\(x_4-x_2)&(y_4-y_2)&(z_4-z_2)\\(x_4-x_3)&(y_4-y_3)&(z_4-z_3)\end{pmatrix}$$

and $$D=\begin{pmatrix}(d_1^2-d_4^2)-(x_1^2-x_4^2)-(y_1^2-y_4^2)-(z_1^2-z_4^2)\\(d_2^2-d_4^2)-(x_2^2-x_4^2)-(y_2^2-y_4^2)-(z_2^2-z_4^2)\\(d_3^2-d_4^2)-(x_3^2-x_4^2)-(y_3^2-y_4^2)-(z_3^2-z_4^2)\end{pmatrix}$$

when i substitute my equation in M and D these are look like

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}(x_4-x_1)&(y_4-y_1)&(h+z-h-z)\\(x_4-x_2)&(y_4-y_2)&(h+z-h-z)\\(x_4-x_3)&(y_4-y_3)&(h+z-h-z)\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}((c_1 \cdot h)^2-(C_4 \cdot h)^2)-(x_1^2-x_4^2)-(y_1^2-y_4^2)-((h+z)^2-(h+z)^2))\\((c_2 \cdot h)^2-(C_4 \cdot h)^2)-(x_1^2-x_4^2)-(y_1^2-y_4^2)-((h+z)^2-(h+z)^2))\\((c_3 \cdot h)^2)-(C_4 \cdot h)^2)-(x_1^2-x_4^2)-(y_1^2-y_4^2)-((h+z)^2-(h+z)^2))\end{pmatrix}$$

at this moment h is eliminate from M and h exist in D so how can i find the value of x,y and h. Is there any other method to solve this equation i prefer by using only three and must be numerical method no  subtraction or multiplication method because in that case error is large.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider your three equations (written as A=0, B=0, C=0). If you substract A from B and A form C expanding the squares, you vill notice that terms x^2 and y^2 disappear and that you just have two linear equations for two unknownx x and y (considereding h as a constant). So, you have x and y as analytical expressions of h. Replace these expressions now in equation A and you have a single equation of h (which is suppose is a quadratic).

If you want to use a least square estimation method, just keep your three equations and three unknowns. At solution, the sum of squares must be zero since you have as many equations and unknowns. Do not add any extra.

Comment: Claude Leibovici , could you explain more details how can i solve by using least square estimation method because you may notice the value of M and D when i substitute my equation in least square equation , there is missing h in M and there is unknown in case of D , so how can you get the value of x, y and h

Comment: @user119767. I did not address the matrix formulation of the solution of the least square problem and I shall not. In terms of least squares, you problem is nonlinear. If you have a nonlinear least square solver, just apply it : you have three equations, three unknowns and then, at solution, the sum of squares MUST be zero. WHat I tried to show you is that you can easily express x and y as functions of h solving two linear equations. What is left is one quartic equation in h, which reduces to a quadratic since only even powers of h appear in it.